# C programming: inline function VS macro

Tags: c

Run the following codes:

Case 1:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int count=0;

    void g(void){
    printf("Called g, count=%d.\n",count);
}

#define EXEC_BUMP(func) (func(),++count)
typedef void(*exec_func)(void); 
inline void exec_bump(exec_func f){
    f();
    ++count;
}

int main(void)
{
    //int count=0;
     while(count++<10){
        EXEC_BUMP(g); 
        //exec_bump(g); 
     }
     return 0;
}
```

---

Case 2：

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count=0;

void g(void){
     printf("Called g, count=%d.\n",count);
}

#define EXEC_BUMP(func) (func(),++count)
typedef void(*exec_func)(void); 
inline void exec_bump(exec_func f){
    f();
    ++count;
}

int main(void)
{
    //int count=0;
    while(count++<10){
        //EXEC_BUMP(g);
        exec_bump(g); 
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

---

Case 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count=0;

void g(void){
     printf("Called g, count=%d.\n",count);
}

#define EXEC_BUMP(func) (func(),++count)
typedef void(*exec_func)(void);
inline void exec_bump(exec_func f){
      f();
     ++count;
}

int main(void)
{
    int count=0;
    while(count++<10){
        //EXEC_BUMP(g); 
        exec_bump(g); 
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

---

Case 4:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count=0;

void g(void){
    printf("Called g, count=%d.\n",count);
}

#define EXEC_BUMP(func) (func(),++count)
typedef void(*exec_func)(void); 
inline void exec_bump(exec_func f){
    f();
    ++count;
}

int main(void)
{
    int count=0;
     while(count++<10){
      EXEC_BUMP(g);
      //exec_bump(g);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

---

The differences among the cases are defining a local variable or not, and using inline function vs. macro.
Why the code above give different output?
Besides, is there anyone can let me know why using the inline function are more efficient than macro.

Output below:

```
Case 1:
    Called g, count=1.
    Called g, count=3.
    Called g, count=5.
    Called g, count=7.
    Called g, count=9.

Case 2:
    Called g, count=1.
    Called g, count=3.
    Called g, count=5.
    Called g, count=7.
    Called g, count=9.


Case 3:
    Called g, count=0.
    Called g, count=1.
    Called g, count=2.
    Called g, count=3.
    Called g, count=4.
    Called g, count=5.
    Called g, count=6.
    Called g, count=7.
    Called g, count=8.
    Called g, count=9.

Case 4:
    Called g, count=0.
    Called g, count=0.
    Called g, count=0.
    Called g, count=0.
    Called g, count=0.
```

Comment: Can you give us the output?

Comment: The disassembly would also be useful here as well as your compiler and compiler/linker settings used to build the code.

Comment: Oh, that's because your macro is incrementing the local variable, and your inline function is incrementing the global one. You named them both `count`.

Comment: The result are provided.@moffeltje

Comment: Using an inline function is more effecient than using a macro if you want type safety, for example

Answer (score 3):

I think your test is kind of comparing apples and oranges, especially case 3 and 4. Your macro is incrementing the local `count` variable, and your inline function is incrementing the global `count` variable.

You named them both `count`, but the macro increments the one within the local scope. It's something you have to watch out for when using macros, since they have no concept of scope.

I would suggest naming that global variable something different from the local counter to avoid the confusion.

### Update for some requested details:

With macros, they're kind of like a brute force 'copy and paste' code generating mechanism with a bit of text substitution. So when you define a macro like:

```
#define FOO (++count)
```

... and invoke that, it's like literally writing `++count` into the function from which you're invoking it. Macro expansion always forcefully inlines code in this sense, and it does so before the compiler and linker even get to it. The preprocessor is a completely separate stage in the build process, and so macros don't respect the same language rules for scoping that an inline function would. We also tend to have to be a bit more careful with them for this reason, since running into a case like your test can be really confusing to debug.

Function inlining, on the other hand, is actually a compile-time (and sometimes even link-time) optimization. The resulting object code or even final binary is made devoid of the normal function calling overhead, of pushing things to the stack, potentially having to pass specific things through exact registers (depending on the calling convention), etc. So you can get a similar kind of performance benefit as macro expansion, but inline functions respect the language's scoping rules.

It's also worth noting that `inline` is more of a hint than anything else, and some compilers just outright ignore it and treat it only as a specifier for internal linkage. You can actually get something faster in a real world scenario if you or the optimizer choose *not* to inline something, as it might help reduce instruction cache misses, for example, or help the optimizer allocate registers for a more common case branch of execution (sometimes inter-procedural optimization actually interferes by reducing your code to a flat playing field, when you might want the optimization to be a bit more skewed towards a common case branch of code, and excessive inlining can actually seem to interfere with this and give worse results).

Macros do not provide such a luxury for the compiler or linker to selectively inline things, but they're a very different kind of code-generating tool. Macros can be used to generate new functions, for example, while inline functions cannot.

Comment: I am trying to know the differences between macro and inline function, can you elaborate more on this, especially how they work in the memory?Thanks.

Comment: @ChongZheng Tried to update the answer to provide some more details as to the differences between macros and inline functions.

Comment: @ChongZheng Macros are part of the C preprocessor. The preprocessor merely performs text replacement. As such, macros are inherently not aware of the concept of scope, or types. They can be equally dangerous if you invoke them with an expression that has side effects, because the expression may be evaluated more than once (depending on how the macro is written). With inline functions, you always get type safety, and no expression is evaluated more than once.

Comment: @lke  thanks, but why using inline function is faster.

Comment: @ChongZheng Inline functions aren't necessarily faster so to speak, but the 'inline' keyword does allow the compiler to ignore it (and sometimes that can actually speed up execution real world cases not to inline).

Comment: @ChongZheng If you're looking more for efficiency advice, I'd recommend sticking to functions whenever you don't need the full-blown code generation capabilities of macros because they're easier to get right and not misuse, and actually not even using the `inline` keyword so much. Then you can apply a profiler like `gprof` over your code when you're interested in speeding it up, and that'll show you exactly where (which lines/functions) the system is spending the most time. After that you can wisely choose whether to inline something or not with good measurements to guide your decisions.

Answer (score 2):

A good start when you want to think about inline functions is, perhaps surprisingly, *to ignore the inline.*

The semantics (the meaning) of a function do not change one bit when it is declared inline. It is just a hint to the compiler to optimize an implementation detail, and the compiler is not forced to honor it. On the other hand the compiler is free to inline functions which are not declared inline, and most modern compilers will do it when executed with optimization options.

The meaning of preprocessor macros, on the other hand, is simple and stupid. It is pure text replacement, happening before the translation phase. All identifiers occuring in the resulting C program text mean whatever they mean at that place in the code.